# javascript for self made radio button isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS for my own radio button; but it doesn't seem to be working; the console logs this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } on line 14.

This is the code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.choise').click(function(){

        $(this).css({"background":"#58D998"});

        });
    if ( $('.choise').css({"background":"#58D998"}) ) 
            {

            $('.choise').click(function()
                {
                $(this).css({"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"});
                }
            }
        );

);
```

I want this code to be working as follows: When clicking for the first time on a button, make the background color X. When hitting it the second time, change it to color Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tg9wx/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.choise').click(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "background": "#58D998"
        });

        if ($('.choise').css({
            "background": "#58D998"
        })) {
            $('.choise').click(function () {
                $(this).css({
                    "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one too many `}` in your second `click` handler.

That being said, your code is ugly and very wrong. It will not toggle.

Why don't you just do this?

```
<label class="choice"><input type="radio" /><span>Click here!</span></label>
<label class="choice"><input type="radio" /><span>Or here!</span></label>
```

And this CSS:

```css
label.choice>input[type=radio] {display:none}
label.choice>input[type=radio]:checked~span {background:#58D998}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Because I don't want an actual radio button, but a button acting like it. I'm quite new to JS and jQuery. Could you please explain to me what's wrong/ugly about it?

Comment: and btw, the second click handler, there's one for the if/else statement and one for the function, right?

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujx6e/) - no visible radio buttons, just buttons acting like them.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple answer:**

[image: Simple Answer, Look at the console]

**More Detailed:**

You're close brace is in the wrong place. Your code should read:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.choise').click(function(){

        $(this).css({"background":"#58D998"});

        });
    if ( $('.choise').css({"background":"#58D998"}) ) 
        {

            $('.choise').click(function()
                {
                $(this).css({"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"});
                }
            );
        }


);
```

As others have pointed out though, this is probably not the best way to go about things.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! I'm very new to JS and jQuery, so could you please tell me why this is? I have no clue about writing nice or ugly...

Comment: try using notepad++ . There you can match braces {}. so you never again get stuck with this kinda problem. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.4.3.html

Comment: First, you have excessive nesting (code inside code) which makes code hard to read, follow, and debug. Second you should have as few string literals and object literals as possible, this is part of what's called DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) code. Third, styling belongs in style sheets. Toggle classes, not properties. This helps to reinforce DRY code. Fourth, this code is way longer than it needs to be, which increases load time and processing, as well as the likelihood of error, and difficulty debugging, in this case trivially because the code is small, but best practices are meant to scale.